# Member's posting permission in google group stick to 'none'

Tags: email, google-groups, permissions

When I select a member in the list, press 'actions' in the menu and choose any posting option (e.g. override to allow posting) it has no effect.
Setting any permission falls back immediately to 'none'. 
Even making this member a manager does not change posting permission.
Member claims to use gmail via 'google for your domain'.

Comment: Can you be more specific with the question? What steps are you taking to try and update permissions?

Comment: I updated the question for you. Standard posting restrictions are loosened: zero moderation and such.

Comment: I would hide the screenshot you included as it has the contact information for a lot of, if not all, of the Groups members.

Comment: Could this problem be caused by you not having the permissions to to override Group default settings? You might have to be listed as an admin or owner to override other user's access

Comment: I am the owner. Members wouldn't see these options. As for retouching the screenshot, I'm kinda lazy doing this right now on tablet. here goes the progress :-)